# Regular expression for only characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I new to regular expression in java script. I want to create a regular expression that will check if a string contains only characters between a-z and A-Z with any arrangement and reverse the words. I tried like below:

```
"Hello%20Bye".split(/([^a-z|A-Z|\.])/).reverse().join('');
```

I want output should like this:`Bye%20Hello`

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

No need of regex here.

1. Decode the string using [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)
2. [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by space
3. [Array#reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array
4. [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array by space as glue
5. Encode the string using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Code:

```
encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("Hello%20Bye").split(' ').reverse().join(' '));
```

```js
var str = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("Hello%20Bye").split(' ').reverse().join(' '));

document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.test()` , `.match()`

```js
var str = "Hello%20Bye"
, re = /[a-z]+/gi;
re.test(str)
, res = str.match(re).reverse().join(str.match(/[^a-z]+/gi)[0]);

document.write(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex allowing only characters between a-z and A-Z with any arrangement:

```
/^[a-z]+$/i
```

#### DESCRIPTION

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### DEMO

https://regex101.com/r/wP3hV4/2

#### SAMPLE CODE

```js
/**
 *
 * @return reversed input string if it contains only characters between a-z and A-Z with any arrangement. 
 * `null' otherwise.
 *
 */
function checkAndReverse(str) {
  var ret = null;
  var regex = /[a-z]+/gi;
  var decodedStr = decodeURIComponent(str);
  var words = decodedStr.split(' ');
  var i = words.length - 1;
  
     while (i >= 0) {
        if (!regex.test(words[i])) {
           break;
        }

        i--;
     }

     if (i < 0) {
        ret = encodeURIComponent(words.reverse().join(' '));
     }

     return ret;
}

var str = "Hello%20Bye";
document.write(checkAndReverse(str));
```